# Can this simple divisibility property on binomial coefficient be proved without Gauss' lemma?

Tags: arithmetic, divisibility

Consider the following property : ( * ) if $n\geq 1$, then
$a_n=\binom{2n}{n}$ is divisible by $2n-1$. One can show that
( * ) is true as follows : $2n-1$ divides $na_n$ (because
of the identity $2(2n-1)a_{n-1}=na_n$) and $n$ and $2n-1$ are coprime,
so that by Gauss' lemma $2n-1$ must divide $a_n$.

The natural reaction to this sort of proof is look for more
"direct" proofs. For example, can $\frac{a_n}{2n-1}$ be written
as an "obviously integral" expression (say, a product of sums
of binomial coefficients or something similar).

Comment: Maybe something like this:

Write out $\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$ and cancel out one of the $n!$. Then one is left to compare terms $(n+k)$ in the numerator vs. $k$ in the denominator.

If $n$ is a multiple of $k$, so is $n+k$, but if not... I don't know how to continue

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an answer that truly satisfies your conditions, because we are working with binomial coefficients. For example, we know that $\binom{2n}{n}$ is integral, but can you write it as an obvious integral expression (combinatorial arguments excluded)?

Every proof will eventually boil down to the coprimality of $2n-1$ and $n$ I guess.